# Google+ Pages API - publishing a post with custom thumbnail of url attachment

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-api-php-client

We are using the G+ Pages API to post into a G+ Page. When creating a post, we enable link attachment with customization of the link thumbnail image.

Sometimes, the API ignores the image url with give it and selects another image (without returning any error message). I'm trying to understand why but I couldn't find any documentation that can provide an explanation.

Here is an example:
This is the url we are attaching to the post: https://business.yell.com/knowledge/attract-right-social-media-audience-increase-followers/

This is the body of the request:

```
{  
   "access":{  
      "items":[  
         {  
            "type":"public"
         }
      ]
   },
   "object":{  
      "attachments":[  
         {  
            "image":{  
               "url":"https:\/\/business.yell.com\/knowledge\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/01\/how-to-attract-the-right-social-media-audience-and-increase-followers.png"
            },
            "objectType":"article",
            "url":"https:\/\/business.yell.com\/knowledge\/attract-right-social-media-audience-increase-followers\/"
         }
      ],
      "originalContent":"content text"
   }
}
```

The image url is from a meta tag (og:image) in the article source, but the API ignores the url and uses a different image from the page.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Well that particular URL returns nothing for the image in the og:image URL.

Comment: @abraham - That was my first thought but I looked at the source code of the url and I see a meta tag with the og:image on it. Also, my crawler picked the tag up. what did I miss? Structure? 

This is the tag I picked up:
<meta property="og:image" content="https://business.yell.com/knowledge/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/how-to-attract-the-right-social-media-audience-and-increase-followers.png" />

Comment: Also, why does the API ignores the image url I give it?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I used facebook open graph object debugger on the url (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and found that

> og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image 'https://business.yell.com/knowledge/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Anna-Bravington_avatar_1418999410.jpg' will be used instead.

If I send a different thumbnail image to FB it uses it but G+ for some reason (which I don't know what it is yet) ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on GooglePage api docs, there are 2 ways to posting an article with an image:

1. Article with an image from Google+ photos : Upload your image to Google+ photos. The image can be any public image from Google+ photos belonging to your Google+ Pages account — the image does not have to be from your target article page. You specify your post (Article) with the image's url using the direct URL returned by the Media.insert method. (Do not specify a private image as its rendering is undefined.)
2. Create an activity with a URL in the attachments array, and POST it with the preview argument set to true. (Example: $plus->activities->insert($remote_id , $activityObj, array("preview"=>true) ) ). This POST will return a preview rendering of your activity, with a list of thumbnail images for you to select from.

This is mean that the object.attachments.image.url have to be either a google+ photo url or a thumbnail image returned from object.attachments.previewThumbnails